# What exactly /guard flag does? (Control Flow Guard)

Tags: windows, visual-c++

With the option [`/guard`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn919635.aspx) in Visual C++ 2015 and above, we can enable **Control Flow Guard** for our program (incompatible with `/ZI` and `/clr`, but that's okay).

What exactly is CFG? The article also says about *CFG-aware* OS - what is CFG-aware Operating system? There is [this article](http://sjc1-te-ftp.trendmicro.com/assets/wp/exploring-control-flow-guard-in-windows10.pdf) but I cannot comprehend it.

Any code example that shows the impact/effect of CFG enabled program (other than simple code I've pasted below) ?

Vaguely, I notice that if some function is called through a (function) pointer, and the address is invalid, it will terminate the application? Is that it? What about Kernel intervention, as is [mentioned here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt637065(v=vs.85).aspx).

Sample code, I have used:

```
void Crash()
{
    void *pff = new int;

    __try
    {   
        ((void(*)())pff)();
    }
    __except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
    {
        std::cout << "Crash";
    }
}
```

This will show "Crash" if /guard is not enabled, crash the program otherwise.
So, is that it? - or anything else also (since Kernel plays important role, program header will have CFG enabled, I think there must be something additional also).

Comment: Yes, that's it.  Just a runtime check that verifies that a non-local branch jumps to known-good code.  Doesn't show the kind of techniques that an attacker would use to turn data into malicious code, but expounding on them isn't exactly this site's goal.